For Unity Shaders how can I clip a readonly shader and render other shaders outside of the clipped material volume
For Unity with standard render Shaders is there a way to clip a plane so that read-only shader inside the volume is removed, but all shaders / materials outside the clip zone are visible?
Limitations

The shader I need to cut through is readonly due to it being a pre-existing shader.

I'm attempting to mask said shader but only in the volume of the area it should be removed. I'd also like to have the shader re-applied to the boundaries of the removed area. (Water displacement)
Use cases:

A bubble at the surface of a water mesh. The view from inside and outside the bubble should reveal underwater objects + allow for transparencies.
Displacing water meshes via boundaries to to remove only the water mesh in the area clipped but allow viewing the mesh when looking through the clipped zone if the same mesh is not within the volume. E.g. the user diving underwater, but returning to a "bubble" of air on the surface or underwater base.

Problems:

If I need a depth mask to remove transparency layer (3000) I need it on a lower layer for a readonly shader that does not take a stencil. (hoping I'm wrong here).
With this in mind, anything on layer 3000 then gets removed when looking through the depth mask.

Am I forced to regenerate all the clipped resources on lower layers after applying this mask? IE if the mask is layer 2999 I would have to find all the shaders/ transparencies I want to continue rendering through the mask and forcing their renderqueue to 2999 instead of 3000?
Tried to do the following

Create a Mask that clips the water plane. This can be done. But it seems like the mask must be on a render queue lower than the plane. Also the lower the render queue the more shaders clipped (all these lost shaders need to be shown outside the clipped area).
Tried creating a cube mask and then surrounding it with another shader using a stencil buffer that allows it to render. It will render that shader, but will clip other renderqueue layers above it still. EG. Setting renderqueue to 2999 will allow ZWrite On to clip renderqueue 3000 which have many of the items needed.

Another odd things is is when I use the same render layer I see the depth mask apply at some angles but not apply at other angles. Wondering if this is this a config issue or just a limitation of sharing a renderqueue and two items not using compatible shaders for clipping?
